# Add a software item to a Zenodo community

Tags: zenodo

I am curator of [a Zenodo community](https://zenodo.org/communities/acute_uera_seminars/records?q=&l=list&p=1&s=10&sort=newest).

I want to add, submit an existing [software](https://zenodo.org/records/10718413) to this community.

The [documentation about submitting a record to a community](https://help.zenodo.org/docs/share/submit-to-community/) says that on the right side there should be a box "Communities" and a cog-wheel icon with the possibility to chose a community. In my case though, the box and the wheel are simply absent, missing.